# How can I rename the header titles of the glossary?

Tags: glossaries

I have tried to rename the header title of the glossary and make the glossary entries bold, to no avail. Could someone help me out pls. merci A

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[acronym,toc,shortcuts]{glossaries}


\makeglossaries

\renewcommand*\entryname{Name}
\renewcommand*\descriptionname{Bedeutung}
\setglossarystyle{long3colheader}


\newglossaryentry{AT}
{
        name=Außentemperatur,
        description={gemessene Außentemperatur}
}

\newglossaryentry{ALT}
{
        name=Auslegungstemperatur,
        description={die minimale Außentemperatur, bei der die Heizlast des Gebäudes  100\% gedeckt ist}
}


\begin{document}

\clearpage
\printglossaries

\newpage


 \gls{AT} 
 \gls{ALT} 


\end{document}
```

Comment: Off-Topic: `\SI{100}{\percent}` improves the display of the `100%`, requires `\usepackage{siunitx}`, however

Comment: What do you mean with `header title`? The name `Glossar`?

Comment: merci Christian

Comment: The correct way to thank users is to upvote and accept answers ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The glossary title can be changed by `\printglossary[type=main,title={foo}]`, for example.

The `\glsnamefont` macro contains the font that should be used for the glossary name entries.

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[acronym,toc,shortcuts]{glossaries}


\makeglossaries

\renewcommand*\entryname{Name}
\renewcommand*\descriptionname{Bedeutung}
\setglossarystyle{long3colheader}


\renewcommand*{\glsnamefont}[1]{\bfseries #1}%

\newglossaryentry{AT}
{
        name=Außentemperatur,
        description={gemessene Außentemperatur}
}

\newglossaryentry{ALT}
{
  name=Auslegungstemperatur,
  description={die minimale Außentemperatur, bei der die Heizlast des Gebäudes  \SI{100}{\percent} gedeckt ist}
}


\begin{document}

\clearpage
\printglossary[type=main,title={Bedeutung}]

\newpage


 \gls{AT} 
 \gls{ALT} 


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great. Merci @Christian;  exactly what I had in mind.

Comment: But what if my glossary is not being printed like that? and in some other programatic way? is there a way to change the title after it is printed? or change a variable?

Comment: Didnt work for me, and even in your screenshot the \entryname and \descriptionname do not match.

Comment: I solved the problmen by using
\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand*{\entryname}{xxxxxxx}}%
seems like this is needed if youre using babel.

Answer (score 2):

As you are using the babel package, you can change the title of the glossary like this:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[acronym,toc,shortcuts]{glossaries}

\addto\captionsngerman{% 
\renewcommand*{\glossaryname}{Bedeutung}%
}
\makeglossaries


\newglossaryentry{AT}
{
        name=Außentemperatur,
        description={gemessene Außentemperatur}
}

\newglossaryentry{ALT}
{
        name=Auslegungstemperatur,
        description={die minimale Außentemperatur, bei der die Heizlast des Gebäudes  100\% gedeckt ist}
}


\begin{document}

\clearpage
\printglossaries

\newpage


 \gls{AT} 
 \gls{ALT} 


\end{document}
```

Comment: I think you need `%` after `\renewcommand*{\glossaryname}{Bedeutung}` otherwise you could end up with an unwanted space if the language switches.

Comment: @NicolaTalbot Thanks a lot for your comment!