# Rename glossary symbol columns, change order of columns

Tags: symbols, glossaries, glossaries-extra

I want to rename the headers in my glossary.
Since [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/426390/how-can-i-rename-the-header-titles-of-the-glossary) link just offers to rename the headers of all used glossaries it sadly is not useful.
Is there a possibility to rename those headers just before `\printglossary` ?

And is it possible to switch the order of those columns or do I have to make my own glossary?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[
    nomain,
    toc,
    stylemods=longbooktabs,
    symbols,
    abbreviations
    ]{glossaries-extra}
\makeglossaries

\newabbreviation{ie}{i.e.}{that is}%
\newabbreviation{wtf}{WTF}{What the f*ck}%

\newglossaryentry{ohm}{name={Ohm},type=symbols,symbol= {\ensuremath{\Omega}},description={unit of electrical resistance}}
\newglossaryentry{ibatt}{name={Batterycurrent},type=symbols,symbol={\ensuremath{I_{batt}}},description={Electric current of the battery}}
\begin{document}

\gls{ie}

\gls{wtf}

\gls{ibatt}
\gls{ohm}
\glssymbol{ibatt}
\glssymbol{ohm}

\printglossary[
    type=abbreviations,
    style=long3col-booktabs,
    ]
\printglossary[
    type=symbols,
    style=altlongragged4col-booktabs
    ]
\end{document}
```